# Way to improve my question to be answerable

Tags: discussion

I wanted to get experience about career but it seem like my question was seaking a "future prediction" answer : "What carrier plan is the best for making money as a Developer?"

Many edits made it better, but it seem like it's not good enough to make it helpfull for other people.
[How can I figure out typical salaries for a specific career path related to IT?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/how-can-i-figure-out-typical-salaries-for-a-specific-career-path-related-to-it?noredirect=1#comment290716_95982)

I'm searching a to turn this to "How to define my career plan, search informations like salary". Thanks for your help !

Comment: The latest version of the question is potentially unclear. Your initial motivation seems to have been how to value the earning potential of different careers or to figure out which one was the most interesting from a financial perspective. The last edits are more "I'm not sure where to take my career, how do I go about planning a career path? What should I look at?". Both are potentially useful questions but they're probably distinct enough to warrant separate questions.

Comment: @Lilienthal I can make two questions ?

Comment: If they are both good ones then yes. :) Basically, on StackExchange we want questions that are clear and about a specific "core question". We don't want questions that ask 4 different things because then the answers might cover only some of those and it's difficult to judge (via upvotes/downvotes) whether an answer is good or not. "How do I find the typical salary progression for a career?" is a very different question from "How do I determine what career is for me?" so if you wanted to ask both those things you'd post two separate questions.

Comment: I would gladly edit the question for you if only it were clear to me what your question was. As it stands, what I guess it is asking for how do I choose a "nice" career path, which is unclear, too broad, primarily opinion based, and seeking advice on what to do. (That's 4 of our close reasons!)